# fb:like when asked to sign in IE doesnt work

Tags: javascript, popup, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I'am adding Facebook Like Button to my website.

I've added the following to my aspx page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
          appId: 'ID',
          status: true,
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
      });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
</script>
```

and this to `html` tag:

```
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"   xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"  prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"
```

and this is my like:

```
<fb:like  send="false" layout="standard" width="350" style="height:22px;" show_faces="false" action="like" colorscheme="light"></fb:like>
```

I did add the meta tags for OpenGraph.

When testing it on all browsers it is working correctly. When not signed in to Facebook and you need to sign-in to like the item a pop up window appears and it closes after you enter correct username and password.

But in IE (9) a window appears and after I enter username and password it redirects to this link: http://www.facebook.com/connect/connect_to_external_page_reload.html

Which is a blank page and nothing happens afterwards, it does not close and I can't like any item.

Even if I'am already signed into Facebook on IE before clicking the like I still get the same thing to enter username and password.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Getting everything to work for me in IE took a whole day.
In the end this is what I did.

1. in the beginning of my page I added the following

   ```
    <html lang="en" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
   ```
2. I added the facebook like and send buttons using XFBML format (for some reason I couldn't get the HTML 5 version to work)
   Note: I also had to add them separately. For some reason when I didn't use FB:Send and used FB:like send="true" it didn't work in IE 10. If you only want the like dont add the FB:Send line.

   ```
    <fb:like href="http://www.domain.com" send="false" layout="button_count" width="60" show_faces="false" action="like" font=""></fb:like>

    <fb:send href="http://www.domain.com"></fb:send>
   ```
3. I added the script into the page

   ```
   <div id="fb-root"></div>`
   <script> (function (d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s);
   js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); </script>
   ```
4. I added the channelUrl to ensure it worked in IE 8 & 9

   ```
   <script>
   window.fbAsyncInit = function () { //fbAsyncInit prevents call of FB.getLoginStatus before the SDK is loaded and/or initialized
       FB.init({
           appId: "You app ID here bunch of digits",
           status: true, // check login status
           cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow server to access session,
           xfbml: true, // enable XFBML and social plugins
           oauth: true, // enable OAuth 2.0
           channelUrl: 'http://channel.html' //custom channel
       });
   };
   ```
5. created the Channel.html file with the following inside

   ```
   <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I found that disabling protected mode setting in IE9 fixes the issue. You can find this on Internet Options -> Security -> Internet -> Enable Protected Mode checkbox. Let me know if that helps.